# is not a valid Win32 application. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800700C1) godaddy

Tags: asp.net

This error after deploy on godaddy  at local it works fine

```
Could not load file or assembly 'ClearScriptV8-32.dll' or one of its dependencies.  is not a valid Win32 application. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800700C1)
```

any solution ?

Comment: Use the installer to install the 32bit, or change your pool from 64bit to 32

Comment: I can't change server pool godaddy , is there dll file i can upload or anything else to solve the problem ?

Comment: first find and include the 64bit dlls - second look what other library may need that dll to run - and install it on server if this is possible (eg ms runtime libraries)